# For a > 0, consider any continuous function f : [−a, a] → R such that f(−a) = f(a). Show that there exists x ∈ [−a, 0] such that f(x) = f(x + a).

Tags: functions, continuity

Im having a bit of trouble getting an answer for this question:

For a > 0, consider any continuous function f : [−a, a] → R such that f(−a) = f(a). Show
that there exists x ∈ [−a, 0] such that f(x) = f(x + a).

I understand how to get a value x between [-a,0] but i cannot seem to show that f(x)=f(x+a). Do you use IVT or some technique to show?

Thanks

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) - f(x+a)$. What can you say about the values of this function at $0$ and at $-a$?